# Regular Expression for to check determinate number

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to make a regular expression that allows me to control decimal numbers with a given pattern.

The rule would be:

Minimum number: 1

Maximum number: 40

Decimal values allowed: .5

I'm trying with: `^([0-4](\.[0-9]*)?|2(\.5))`

Comment: Done! Sorry for my bad kick-off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?:(?:(?:[1-9]|[1-3][0-9])(\.5)?)|40)$
```

Try this.See Demo.

http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/36

Answer (score 0):

```
^([0-4][\d](\.[0-5]*)?)$
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: This doesn't match `1.5` but matches `49.012345012345`